# How to periodically show alert message *in foreground*?

Tags: macos, applescript, launchd

I want to have an alert / dialog box to fire up periodically **in foreground**.

I tried a combination of AppleScript and `launchd` and managed to have the script (actually converted to a app) fired up periodically via launchd. However, the alert box does not show up in front of all other windows (rather totally hidden until I tab to it – though it *does* get started via `launchd`). How can I get it in front?

My script is as follows:

```
on run
    activate me --> tried to get alert in foreground
                --> didn't help, though
    display alert "Should show up in foreground..."
end run
```

My launch.plist is (in `/Users/bernhard/Library/LaunchAgents/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>bernhard.sitstraight.plist</string>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/bernhard/programming/periodic.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
    <true/>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1200</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) instead of launching the program directly. `open` more closely matches double-clicking to launch the AppleScript application.

### `open` your application

To do this, replace the `Program` key value pair in your launchd job ticket with a `ProgramArguments` array to provide the path to your AppleScript application:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
    <string>/Users/bernhard/programming/periodic.app</string>
</array>
```

By default, the `open` command attempts to bring the launched application to foreground.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost the solution. However, the `ProgramArguments` need some program name (passed as `argv[0]`) as first argument (see [launchd.info](http://launchd.info) -> Configuration). With this modification it works :)

Comment: Great to hear the `open` approach worked. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work ok on my 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard), though I didn't launch it from `launchd`.

I did something very similar to monitor my battery. The script automatically hibernates my system after giving a 60s count down using a 'flashing' dialog box.

Because, like you, the dialog box would sometimes get buried, I gave the dialog box a timeout and would re-display it.

Here is the relevant code applescript code from my bash schell script...

```
   userResp="`/usr/bin/osascript 2>&1 <<-EOF
    tell application "System Events"
        activate
        display dialog \
            "Battery below min safe level of ${minBattLvl}%" \
            & "\\n\\nForcing hibernation in: ${cntDown} seconds." \
            as text buttons {"Cancel","$btntext"} \
            default button "$btntext" \
            with icon caution \
            with title "WARNING: Battery Monitor" \
            giving up after $dlgTimeout
    end tell
EOF`"
```

Comment: My problem is that the box does not show up in front in the first place (actually not at all until I tab to it). Without launching it via `launchd` it works fine for me as well. I guess it has something to do with the combination of firing it up with `launchd` and the the program being a app...

Comment: Gotcha. Mine was intermittent and sometime accidental - by clicking on another window at the moment the dialog appeared :( . I wonder though if using `System Events` to display the dialog box makes a difference. In any case I'm happy you found a working solution.